# How to split a DStream given a matcher

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Given

```
val dstream = ssc.createStream(..)
```

How do we obtain a bucketed/grouped/split set of Dstreams from it, along the following lines:

```
val (s1, s2, s3): (DStream[_],DStream[_],DStream[_]) = 
   dstream.map{ in match =>
     case <cond1> => bucket1Value
     case <cond2> => bucket2Value
     case _ => bucket3Value
  }.<some bucketing/grouping operation>
```

RE: **Possible Duplicate**  That is a **completely different question** - that other one is about **RDD**'s not **DStream**'s!

Comment: @LostInOverflow  DStream's are quite different than RDD's - why would you suggest they were the same?

Comment: @LostInOverflow if you agree with the OP's comment can you please undo you flag? (possible if you click "flag" again, you'll see a button)

Comment: DStream is a seq of RDDs and every op is applied on RDDs so splitting DStream  is the same problem as splitting RDD. If there is solution to split RDD there is a solution to split DStream. And it goes in opposite dir.

Comment: @LostInOverflow  Show me the method `groupBy` on a `DStream`.  Or for that matter another twenty-plus RDD specific methods.  For the particulars of the problem I am trying to solve using `groupBy` on an `RDD` would work. `DStream` does not have that directly.   Are you suggesting that `forEachRDD` were the  same as having a single non-streamed `RDD`??

Comment: No, I suggest that `DStream.transform` can be used to expose __any RDD method__. So `stream.transform(rdd => rdd.groupBy ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: but if anyone (anyone?) has a suggestion to perform the operation directly it would be gladly accepted.

So here is *a* solution - though not elegant.

```
val s1 = dstream.flatMap{ in match =>
     case r if <cond1> => bucket1Value
     case _            => None
}
val s2 = dstream.flatMap{ in match =>
     case r if <cond2> => bucket1Value
     case _            => None
}
val s3 = dstream.flatMap{ in match =>
     case r if !<cond1> && !<cond2> => bucket3Value
     case _            => None
}
```